# Generating graphics in a web page with CloudDeploy and FormFunction

Tags: graphics, wolfram-cloud

When I execute this code locally on my laptop...

```
myForm = FormFunction[{"poop" -> "Number"}, 
   Module[{}, ode = x'[t] == #poop x[t];
     initialCondition = x[0] == 1;
     solution = NDSolve[{ode, initialCondition}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}];
     Plot[x[t] /. solution, {t, 0, 1}]] &];

myForm[]
```

... a form is returned that prompts me to enter a numerical value for a parameter called "poop". If I enter the number 2 into this form and click "Submit", this plot is returned:

[image]

When I execute this code instead...

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"poop" -> "Number"},
   Module[{}, ode = x'[t] == #poop x[t];
    initialCondition = x[0] == 1;
    solution = NDSolve[{ode, initialCondition}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}];
    Plot[x[t] /. solution, {t, 0, 1}]] &]]
```

... a link is returned to a web page on which a similar form appears. If I enter the number 2 into this form and click "Submit", a page is returned that displays this Graphics command instead of a plot:

[image]

If I paste this Graphics command into Mathematica locally, the plot above is returned.

I'd like to know how I should alter my second block of code so that the plot appears in my browser in response to my submitting a number through the web-based form.

I can get the plot to appear in my browser by executing a command like this...

```
CloudDeploy[Module[{},
  myForm = 
   FormFunction[{"poop" -> "Number"}, 
    Module[{}, ode = x'[t] == #poop x[t];
      initialCondition = x[0] == 1;
      solution = NDSolve[{ode, initialCondition}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}];
      Plot[x[t] /. solution, {t, 0, 1}]] &];
  myForm[]]]
```

... but in this case the form prompting me to enter the number "poop" appears locally on my machine and a web link is returned only after I've submitted a value.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Is this still the case? If so, adding appriopriate `ExportForm` for `FormFunction's` result should handle such cases. Since I can't reproduce it and you were not around for a long time I will close it, but let me know if you disagree or want to update it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: You can wrap Rasterize around the final Plot, which then produces an image file of the plot that is displayed correctly in the browser rather than the wall of underlying InputForm style code.  However, that's clearly insufficient if the output of the "myForm" function is to be in any way interactive (e.g. a tooltip on the plot, a hyperlink in something below the plot, etc.) as rasterizing eliminates interactivity.

Comment: Alternatively, `FormFunction` takes a third argument of format, fmt, that is shown in the documentation as accepting rasterized formats as well as (upon testing) PDF, etc.  The PDF will retain some degree of interactivity (e.g. hyperlinks will work).